# Recursive Function Type error

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I am trying to do a recursive function for Pascal triangle to calculate a specific value in a given row , below is my code and I keep getting the following error :

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

My code so far:

```
def recursive_pascal(i,j):      
   if i == 0:          
     return 1
   elif j == 1:          
     return 1
   else:
     recursive_pascal(i-1,j-1) + recursive_pascal(i-1,j)

print(recursive_pascal(3,2))
```

Answer (score 5):

You are not returning anything from the `else` clause. In Python, if you do not return anything from a function, a value of `None` will be returned. Your function will then attempt to add a `None` and an `int` (which you return from your base case), which is not possible and is why you are receiving that error. You should change it to

```
return recursive_pascal(i-1,j-1) + recursive_pascal(i-1,j)
```

Comment: Ah what a silly mistake, thank you very much @Erik Godard

Comment: No problem, make sure to accept the answer if it was useful to you.